# Python Minimization Functions: Is the code optimal?

Tags: python

I am rather new to python and am porting my R functions into python. I have written the functions below and the primary function is called `thetaMax`. That function minimizes a likelihood function or optionally minimizes a posterior distribution, depending on the option selected by method. The function works exactly as intended and I have unit tested this against my R code.

However, because I am not familiar with pythonic ways of doing this, I am curious what parts of the code below could be improved to 1) write less/more compact code and 2) to improve speed and take advantage of vectorization when possible?

A complete reproducible example is below

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom  
from scipy.optimize import minimize  
from scipy.stats import norm

def prob3pl(theta, a, b, c, D = 1.7): 
    result = c + (1 - c) / (1 + np.exp(-D * a * (theta - b)))
    return(result)        

def gpcm(theta, d, score, a, D = 1.7):
    Da = D * a
    result = np.exp(np.sum(Da * (theta - d[0:score])))/np.sum(np.exp(np.cumsum(Da * (theta - d))))
    return(result)

def thetaMax(x, indDichot, a, b, c, D, d, method = 'mle', **kwargs):
    method_options = ['mle', 'map']
    optional_args = kwargs
    if method not in method_options:
        raise ValueError("Invalid method. Expected one of: %s" % method_options)
    if method == 'map' and 'mu' not in optional_args:
        raise ValueError("You must enter a value for 'mu' for the posterior distribution. Example, mu = 0")
    if method == 'map' and 'sigma' not in optional_args:
        raise ValueError("You must enter a value for 'sigma' for the posterior distribution. Example, sigma = 1")        
    x1 = x[indDichot]
    x2 = np.delete(x, indDichot)
    result = [0] * len(x2)
    def fn(theta):
        if(len(x1) > 0):
            p = prob3pl(theta, a, b, c, D = D)
            logDichPart = np.log(binom.pmf(x1,1,p)).sum()
        else: 
            logPolyPart = 0     
        if(len(x2) > 0):
            for i in range(0,len(x2)):
                result[i] = gpcm(theta, d = d[i], score = x2[i], a = 1, D = D)        
            logPolyPart = np.log(result).sum()
        else:
            logPolyPart = 0
        if(method == 'mle'):
            LL = -(logDichPart + logPolyPart)
        elif(method == 'map'):        
            normal = np.log(norm.pdf(theta, loc = optional_args['mu'], scale = optional_args['sigma']))
            LL = -(logDichPart + logPolyPart + normal)
        return(LL)
    out = minimize(fn, x0=0)
    return(out)


### In order to run
d = np.array([[0, -1, .5, 1],[0,-.5,.2,1]])
a = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
b = np.array([-1,.5,-.5,0,2])
c = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])
#x = np.array([1,1,0,1,0])
x = np.array([1,1,0,1,0,1,1])
indDichot = range(0,5,1) 

object = py.thetaMax(x,indDichot,a,b,c,D=1,d = d)
```

Comment: This is not a "complete reproducible example": `NameError: name 'py' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

## PEP-8 Violations

The [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) enumerates many conventions that all Python code should follow.  You have deviated from these conventions in several areas:

1. `mixedCase` is discouraged.  Function names, methods and variable should all be `snake_case`.  This means `thetaMax` should be called `theta_max`.  (Exceptions are allowed for things like `Da`, where consistency with mathematical notation is more important than consistency with Python style.)
2. `return` is not a function call; it should not have parenthesis.  Ie) `return(result)` should be written as `return result`.
3. `if` is also not a function call, nor is Python a C-like language; it should not have parenthesis.  `if(method == 'mle'):` should be written as `if method == 'mle':`
4. Binary operators should have one space before and after it.  This is only violated by the division operation in `gpcm` from my quick perusal of the code.
5. Commas should be followed by one space.
6. The equal sign used in `keyword=parameter` should not have a space before or after it.  This applies both to the function definitions `def gpcm(theta, d, score, a, D=1.7):` and function calls `p = prob3pl(theta, a, b, c, D=D)`
7. Builtin Python identifiers should not be redefined without reason.  `object` is such an identifier.  A better name should be used.

## Truthiness of lists.

A container used in a boolean context is `True` if the container is not empty, and `False` if the container is empty.  There is no need to fetch the length of the container, test that value is greater than zero:

```
if x1:
```

is more "Pythonic" than:

```
if(len(x1) > 0):
```

## Ranges Start at Zero by Default

By default, all ranges start at 0.  This means `range(0, len(x2))` is much more commonly written as `range(len(x2))`.

## Iteration over a container

Python is a scripting language, where the script can assign its own implementation for many operations including subscripting, and iteration.  This makes it impossible for Python to optimize code like:

```
for i in range(0, len(x2)):
    ... use the value x2[i] ...
```

It will usually be more efficiently written as:

```
for x2_i in x2:
    ... use the value x2_i ...
```

If the index is needed along with the values, then `enumerate()` is used for the most efficient result:

```
for i, x2_i in enumerate(x2):
    result[i] = gpcm(theta, d=d[i], score=x2_i, a=1, D=D)
```

Iterating over two (or more) parallel list (`d` and `x2`) would be done using zip:

```
for d_i, x2_i in zip(d, x2):
    ... = gpcm(theta, d=d_i, score=x2_i, a=1, D=D)
```

And if the indices are also needed, `enumerate(zip(...))`:

```
for i, (d_i, x2_i) in enumerate(zip(d, x2)):
    result[i] = gpcm(theta, d=d_i, score=x2_i, a=1, D=D)
```

But building up a complete array is more commonly done with list comprehension:

```
result = [ gpcm(theta, d=d_i, score=x2_i, a=1, D=D) for d_i, x2_i in zip(d, x2) ]
```

which eliminates the need for the `result = [0] * len(x2)` pre-allocation.

## Keyword Arguments

What arguments can be passed to `thetaMax()`?

The answer is "any".  The user has no way of knowing what is possible, or allowed.  You can pass `optimization_level=18` without error ... and without effect.

It would be safer to define the function with the allowed keyword arguments explicitly:

```
def thetaMax(x, indDichot, a, b, c, D, d, method='mle', *, mu=None, sigma=None):

    if method not in {'mle', 'map'}:
        raise ValueError("Invalid method")
    if method == 'map':
        if mu is None or sigma is None:
            raise ValueError("Both mu= and sigma= keyword arguments must be given")
    elif method == 'mle':
        if mu is not None or sigma is not None:
            raise ValueErorr("Neither mu= or sigma= is appropriate for 'mle'")
```

As a bonus, having the values already extracted into their own variables is faster than repeatedly looking up `optional_args['mu']` and `optional_args['sigma']` during each and every call of `fn()` during the minimize function.

Additional speed may come from defining different `fn()` functions for the 6 different combinations of `len(x1) > 0`, `len(x2) > 0`, and `method`, thus removing the conditionals from inside the nested calls.

Comment: wow, what a thorough and helpful review. Thank you!